# C++ addres to memory and pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am reading a great book by Stephen Prata. Unfortunately I don't understand something. It is about array and pointers. So there is array tab.
He wrote, that tab is the address for first element of array -> that is ok,
but &tab is address for whole array <- I don't understand this.
What does it means? &tab shows all address of array (of course not), middle address of all elements of array, the last one?

Comment: &tab returns the first address of the array

Comment: `tab` **is** an array, but it **decays** to a pointer to the first element of the array.

Comment: I thought that, but I make the programme, which compare it and there are two other addresses.

Comment: Is it possible to live both in the USA and also in New York?

Comment: tab and &tab are different. So what exactly &tab point?

Comment: Built-in Arrays are strange artifacts of history. In modern C++ you can use `std::array` which follows the same rules as everything else.

Comment: @diego9403 tab and &tab has the same address, but they have different types. if you have `int tab[10]`, then `tab` is the same as &tab[0] and it has the type `int*`, while &tab has the type `int (*)[10] ` ( a pointer to an array of 10 ints,  Also, you pretty much never need to take the address of an array like that)

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ there are two aspects to a pointer:

- The memory address it points to
- The type of what it is pointing to

`tab` and `&tab` indicate the same address, but they have different type. They denote different objects:  `&tab` is a large array, and `tab` (aka. `&tab[0]`) is a sub-object of that array.

It's no different to this situation:

```
struct S
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

S s;

S *p1 = &s;
int *p2 = &s.x;
```

In this case `p1` and `p2` both point to the same address, but they have different types, and point to different objects which occupy the same space.

Answer (score 0):

> tab is the address for first element of array

this is correct, for `char arr[1];` you can write `char* p = arr;`, here we say that arr decays to pointer to its first element.

> &tab is address for whole array

it means its ***type*** is a pointer to array, ie. `char(*)[1]`. Their pointer values (arr and &arr) are equal but the types differ. So below will compile:

```
char (*pp)[1] = &arr; // pointer to array
char (&rp)[1] = arr; // reference to array
```

but this will not compile:

```
char* pp = &arr; // error, types differ
```

You can use below trick to find what type given expression/variable really is. Compiler will show you an error from which you can read actual types:

```
template <typename T>
struct TD;

int main()
{
char arr[1];

//char* pp = &arr; // error, types differ

TD<decltype(arr)> dd;    // is char[1], no decay to char* here
TD<decltype(&arr[0])> dd;    // is char*
//TD<arr> dd;     // char(*)[1]
}
```